# How do you compare two files containing C code based on code structure, not merely textual differences?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, comparison, diff

I have two files containing C code which I wish to compare. I'm looking for a utility which will construct a syntax tree for each file, and compare the syntax trees, instead of merely comparing the text of the files. This way minor differences in formatting and style will be ignored. It would be nice to even be able to tell the comparison tool to ignore differences such as variable names, etc.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but diff doesn't have this capability. I'm a Ubuntu user. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework plagiarism detection?  Lots of packages for that if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: You can get partway there by normalizing the format of the input, then diffing. The `indent` utility is great for that. I can't give you a list of options off the top of my head, but it can swallow up blank lines, standardize brace format and spacing, and so on. Variable names are going to be a lot trickier.

Comment: I suppose it could be used for that purpose, but I'm actually going to be using it to compare two files which I wrote. Would you mind posting the names of any plagiarism detection utilities with which you're familiar? Perhaps they could be of help to me. Thanks!

Comment: This might help. http://www.drdobbs.com/184405734;jsessionid=QTKHWEONNLWW1QE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called codeCompare from devart  (http://www.devart.com/codecompare/benefits.html#cc) that includes the following feature (I know it is not exactly what you asked for but probably it can be used for that).

The feature is called "Structure Comparison"

> This functionality allows you to compare different file revision by the presense of the structure blocks (classes, fields, methods). At that different versions of the same file are compared independently from their destination.
>
> Structure comparison can be applied to the following languages:
>
> - C#
> - C++
> - Visual Basic
> - JavaScript

(I know it does not include C, but maybe with the C++ version you can solve the problem)

Answer (score 2):

Our [SD Smart Differencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) does exactly what you want.   It uses compiler-quality parsers to read source code and build ASTs for two files you select.  It then compares the trees guided by the syntax, so it doesn't get confused by whitespace, layout or comments. Because it normalize the values of constants, it doesn't get confused by change of radix or how you expressed escape sequences!

The deltas are reported at the level of the langauge constructs (variable, expression, statement, declaration, function, ...) in terms of programmer intent (delete, insert, copy, move) complete with determining that an identifier has been renamed consistently throughout a changed block.

The SmartDifferencer has versions available for C (in a number of dialects; if you compiler-accurate parse, the langauge dialect matters) was well as for C++, Java, C#, JavaScript, COBOL, Python and many other langauges.

If you want to understand how a set of files are related to one another, our [SD CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) will accept a very large set of files, and tell you what they have in common.  It finds code that has been copy-paste-edited across the entire set. You don't have to tell it what to look for; it finds it automatically.  Using ASTs (as above), it isn't fooled by whitespace changes or renames of identifiers.  There's a bunch of sample clone detection reports for various languages at the web site.